# How to use the same IP for dom0 and one domU in XEN

Tags: xen, bridge

I have currently a Xen on a debian wheezy dom0.
I have 6 (public) ips and I would like to setup 6 VMs (each using one IP).

To keep access to dom0, I'd like dom0 ssh to bind on one IP port (lets say 4444).
I don't really know where to start. Any pointers ?

Comment: It's best if you get _seven_ IP addresses here.

Comment: Sure, but I would like to stick with 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I finally came up with a solution that I will details :

In this exemple, we have one physical network interface (`eth0`), 3 IPs and 3 VMs :

- `a.a.a.a` (that will be shared by dom0 and one domU called `VM_A`)
- `b.b.b.b` (for one domU `VM_B`)
- `b.b.b.c` (for one domU `VM_C`)

dom0 /etc/network/interface:

```
auto xenbr0 
iface xenbr0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0
    address a.a.a.a
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network a.a.a.0
    broadcast a.a.a.255
    gateway a.a.a.254
```

The default vif script used in `/etc/xen/xend-config.sx` will be `(vif-script vif-bridge)`. This is for `VM_B` and `VM_C` which have their own ip.

For the configuration script of `VM_B` and `VM_C` (/etc/xen/VM_[BC].cfg) we will have :

```
vif = [ 'ip=b.b.b.b,mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX' ]
```

For the configuration script of `VM_A` (/etc/xen/VM_A.cfg) we will have :

```
vif = [ 'ip=192.168.0.1,script=vif-nat']
```

We have to add iptables rules in order to make `VM_A` visible to Internet :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.1 -o xenbr0  -j MASQUERADE
# One rule for each port that need to be forwarded to `VM_A`
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d a.a.a.a --dport 22 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d a.a.a.a --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80
```

Also need to enable packet forwarding (`/etc/sysctl.conf`):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp=1
```

And finally here is how the `/etc/network/interfaces` of `VM_A` looks like :

```
 # The loopback network interface
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 # 'Fake' loopback interfaces (was needed in my case for some applications)
 auto lo:1
 iface lo:1 inet static
  address a.a.a.a
  netmask 255.255.255.255

 # The primary network interface
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.1
  gateway 192.168.0.128
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The gateway address `192.168.0.128` is selected by the `vif_script` by adding 127 to the given address.

And a last thing for the communication between `VM_A` and the other VMs (however, don't ask me why...):

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

Comment: thanks for an excellent walk-thorugh! could you please what this line does: net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp=1

Comment: and could you please post the config of /etc/network/interfaces in VM_A?

Comment: I added the `/etc/network/interfaces` of `VM_A`. For the `arp_proxy`, I think it is for the bridged IPs, not quite sure though.